# How can we prove that the field of complex number is not isomorphic to the field of real numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove this using contradiction, supposing that there is a ring isomorphism between the two and then finding a contradiction.

Answer (score 16):

Is there an element $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a^2=-1$?

---

Added from comments.

Suppose $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an isomorphism. It's usually required that field homomorphisms map $1$ into $1$, but it's not necessary to make this assumption here. Indeed, set $x=f(1)$. Then
$$
x=f(1)=f(1^2)=f(1)f(1)=x^2
$$
so $x-x^2=0$, which means $x=0$ or $x=1$ because we're in a field. If $f(1)=0$, then, for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, we have
$$
f(z)=f(z\cdot1)=f(z)f(1)=f(z)\cdot0=0
$$
which is impossible, because $f$ is bijective (injectivity is sufficient).

Thus $f(1)=1$, hence $f(-1)=-1$. Now $a=f(i)$ would have the property that $a^2=f(i^2)=f(-1)=-1$ and there's no such element $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: No there is not, so we know f(1)=f(1^2)=f(1)^2=1^2=1, this implies that f(-1)=-1 because 0=f(0)=f(1-1)=f(1)+f(-1) and since f(1)=1, f(-1) must equal -1. So if we consider f(i)^2=f(i^2)=f(-1)=-1, this implies that -1 is the square of some number in the real numbers which is impossible. Is this correct?

Comment: @Jenny Yes, correct.

Comment: How do we know that f(1)=1 though?

Comment: @Jenny Set $x=f(1)$; then $x=f(1)=f(1^2)=f(1)^2=x^2$. So either $x=0$ or $x=1$; but $f(1)=0$ implies $f(a)=0$ for all $a$ (why?). Impossible, because $f$ is bijective.

Comment: I do not understand why f(1) cannot be 0. Could you help me understand this?

Comment: @Jenny If $f(1)=0$, then $f(a)=f(a\cdot1)=f(a)f(1)=f(a)\cdot0=0$ for all $a$.

Comment: One last question, how can we do a mini proof of why f(-1)=-1? I tried and figured out how to do it using f(0)=0 but we have not shown that either.

Comment: @Jenny That's true for any ring homomorphism that maps $1$ into $1$. And it's easy.

Comment: I do not understand why f(1) = 1 implies f(-1) = -1.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Because $f(0)=0$ and $f(0)=f(1+(-1))=f(1)+f(-1)=1+f(-1)$.

Comment: @egreg OK thanks,  and do I understand correctly that : f(0) = 0 because for any isomorphism the identity elements must be paired together.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$, so an additive group homomorphism must send $0$ to $0$. Since $f(1)=f(1^2)=(f(1))^2$, we get that $f(1)=0$ or $f(1)=1$ (because $\mathbb{C}$ is a field). Thus, even if we don't assume that $f(1)=1$, we get it, because $f(1)=0$ implies $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, so certainly $f$ wouldn't be an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If the field of complex numbers were isomorphic to the field of real numbers, there would be no reason to define the notion of complex numbers when we already have the real numbers.  But there is such a reason.  (What is it?)

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{C}$ has a nontrivial ring automorphism, $\mathbb{R}$ not.